# Running a Hash through an MD5 hashing algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, hash, md5

I'm new to hashing things and I'd like to be able to run a Hash through the MD5 hash to produce a unique value.  At the moment I'm simply converting the Hash to a string and then just running that through the MD5 algorithm.

Is this a good way to do this or is there a better way to encrypt a Hash using MD5?

To clarify I'm trying to create a cache key for an object that doesn't have a unique id, so I'm trying to use the hash to create an id.

Comment: Be careful with the word encrypt, things that are encrypted can be decrypted. There is no way to get the original bag with only a checksum like MD5.

Comment: @Sqeaky `MD5` can be reverse back it's a weak hashing algorithm, see a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=decrypt+md5&oq=decr&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3598j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) for example, OP if you want a non-reversable hashing algorithm [bcrypt](https://rubygems.org/gems/bcrypt-ruby) seems to be the new hotness

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Updated my question to clarify what I'm trying to do

Comment: @bjhaid Reversing a weak cryptographic hash does not mean the data is recoverable. An MD5 hash is only 128 bits, yet I can MD5sum a 20gb file. A weak hash is one where invalid data can be made to have the same checksum as actually valid data. For example: I could install a virus in an OS install disc image and in a few hours of twiddling bits I could make my malicious OS disc have the same checksum as the valid one. Cryptographic hashes try hard to make this kind of attack computationally expense to the point of impossible.

Comment: I think your approach is good, it's how I'd do it as well. Another option would be to use the object id: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-object_id which is unique to the object, however, this would be different if the object is recreated. Could you tell us your specific use case? for instance, if you had two Hashes that have the same items within them, would you like them to hash to the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby hash built in support for Murmur3 hashing. If you are commited to md5 hashes then using this will not work. If you can use it, then just call the .hash method from the Object class ( http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-hash ).

```
pry(main)> {}.hash
=> 0
pry(main)> {:a => "b"}.hash
=> 2051585302280555993
pry(main)> "foo".hash
=> -2886254516463342771
```

Murmur3 hashes are faster then md5, but may not be suitable for cryptographic uses. If you must use MD5 I see no reason why hashing a string is fundamentally bad. It may even ease to recreating the same hash in languages other than Ruby if required, because it separates the implementation from Ruby's internal binary format.

If you must use a cryptographic hash but are not committed to MD5, please use BCrypt, SHA1 or SHA256. MD5 is trivially reversible and not suitable for securing data.

edit: details and grammar

Comment: Please don't shoot from the hip like this when cryptographic primitives are involved.

Comment: This question appears to be about algorithms and not crypto. If it is about about crypto, when TheDelChop reads my answer and if he is responsible he perform his own research or will ask why MD5 is bad and we can have a real discussion. If he is not responsible, then the advice to use a better algorithm is all the good I might accomplish.

Comment: *appears* I rest my case.

Comment: This isn't about crypto, its about creating unique cache keys from a hash.